# why do omp functions not work when constants are declared in a module?

Tags: module, compiler-errors, openmp, fortran90, gfortran

i have a module 'gvars' defined for my global variable declarations. when i define 
`integer :: nthreads, max_threads, tid, omp_get_max_threads, omp_get_num_threads, omp_get_thread_num` inside of my gvars module, the call `maxthreads = omp_get_max_threads()` in my main routine gives me the following error upon compilation:

```
maxthreads = omp_get_max_threads()
1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

but when i include the `integer ::` definitions above inside my main routine, it compiles just fine and gives me the desired results. if i even go as far as to define `nthreads = -1` inside my gvars module, i am able to print out the correct value in my main routine so i know it is being included and defined correctly, it's just that for some reason i cannot have it as a return value from openmp functions.

why would this be?

is there any other way to keep these values as global variables and still define them in my main routine instead of a module?

if it matters, i am using gfortran to compile

Comment: Do you actually use gvars? Is maxthreads in gvars publicly accessible? It works for me.

Comment: maxthreads in gvars is definitely accessible. when i define nthreads to a given value in gvars, i can print that same value from the main routine. how on earth does this work for you?! can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the declaration of `maxthreads`, but with the declaration, on the same line, of `omp_get_max_threads`. As haraldkl showed, you need to `use omp_lib` instead, to automatically get access to the declarations of these functions.

(If for some reason you really don't want to do it that way, you can also add the statement `external :: omp_get_max_threads, ...` to the module.)

Comment: if i want to make sure these variables (maxthreads, numthreads, etc) are global, will i need to 'use omp_lib' inside my 'gvars' module?

Comment: What do you mean by global? If you use it in gvars, and do not declare a private statement in gvars, the contents of omp_lib should get available everywhere where you use gvars. Though I think using omp_lib everywhere, where it is actually needed is more transparent to readers.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but I do not know how else to put the code in here. Sorry...

```
 module gvars
   integer :: maxthreads
 end module gvars

 program test
  use gvars
  use omp_lib

  implicit none

  maxthreads = omp_get_max_threads()
 end program test
```

compiled with:
   gfortran -fopenmp test.f90

Where gfotran -v gives:
gcc version 4.4.5 (GCC)